# Updating JCombobox items listening for source changes

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jcombobox, itemlistener

I have a JComboBox populated from a directory content (text files). My application writes new files into the same directory so i need to update jcombobox items. How can i do it listening for directory content changes?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the [Observer Observable](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077258/learn-java/observer-and-observable.html) design pattern is a perfect fit for this problem.

Comment: Take a look at [Watching a Directory for Changes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, i'm reading that page and hope to find the solution.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MadProgrammer i solved with WatchService.It was exactly what i needed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with WatchService. Thanks to @MadProgrammer